# Extract the string after particular pattern value before and after

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas data frame and I'd like to extract the values after pb~ and before _ or ' ' or ''.
so it's like the string pb~value_ or pb~value' ' or pb~value''.

```
    import pandas as pd

data = {'PName': ['ag~fbai-churnsoon_mk~de_at~lia_sa~fcs_tg~fbai_ts~alldevice-allgender-13-65_md~c_pb~fcbk_rt~cpm',
                  'pb~precision disclosed desktop_sz~300x600_pd~halfp-dmp-hubble w tablets_ch~dis_dt~dt_fm~ban_it~poe_vv~si_ad~as_rt~cpm_tg~rtg_sa~redc_ts~none_md~w_ff~pr-teas-rt']}

# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
# print the data
```

expected Output

```
    PName                                                                                                                                                               Values
    ag~fbai-churnsoon_mk~de_at~lia_sa~fcs_tg~fbai_ts~alldevice-allgender-13-65_md~c_pb~fcbk_rt~cpm                                                                      fcbk
    pb~precision disclosed desktop_sz~300x600_pd~halfp-dmp-hubble w tablets_ch~dis_dt~dt_fm~ban_it~poe_vv~si_ad~as_rt~cpm_tg~rtg_sa~redc_ts~none_md~w_ff~pr-teas-rt     precision
```

I tried with

```
df['value'] = df['PName'].str.extract("")
```

but not able to figure out how can I extract the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
data = {'PName': ['ag~fbai-churnsoon_mk~de_at~lia_sa~fcs_tg~fbai_ts~alldevice-allgender-13-65_md~c_pb~fcbk_rt~cpm',
                  'pb~precision disclosed desktop_sz~300x600_pd~halfp-dmp-hubble w tablets_ch~dis_dt~dt_fm~ban_it~poe_vv~si_ad~as_rt~cpm_tg~rtg_sa~redc_ts~none_md~w_ff~pr-teas-rt']}

# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['value'] = df['PName'].apply(lambda x :re.findall('pb~([\s\S]*?)(?:_| )',x)[0])
df
    PName   value
0   ag~fbai-churnsoon_mk~de_at~lia_sa~fcs_tg~fbai_...   fcbk
1   pb~precision disclosed desktop_sz~300x600_pd~h...   precision
```

Answer (score 0):

Try non-greedy(lazy) matching

```
df['PName'].str.extract(r'pb~(.+?)[_ ]')

Out[55]:
           0
0  fcbk
1  precision
```